# Chage the default language of an Android app

Tags: android, localization

Iʼm developing an app with only Czech content. If I understood Android documentation correctly, the default language of every Android app is English. But that doesnʼt work for me, as Iʼm using quantity strings which have different grammatical rules in Czech, so pluralization doesnʼt work correctly. I need a way to force the locale of the default string resources to `cs` to fix it. Iʼm aware I can just create a new resource XML for the Czech locale and override the strings there, but Iʼd like to work around that because then Iʼd have the same strings in two different resource files. (Also that would make the plurals broken again on non-Czech devices.)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Actually the default values can be in any language. The localisation of the values file will imply that, if the active locale on the device is that one, it will display those values, otherwise it will display the default values. So put your Czech strings in the default values.xml and you will be fine.

Comment: as for the pluralisation rules the one, zero, many, other options aren't enough?

Comment: @TibiG in Czech I need three different strings: one, few (2-4), other

Comment: and in English few applies to a different interval?

Comment: @TibiG the `few` variant is completely ignored in the default `strings.xml` (the value for `other` is used even for quantities 2-4), so I suppose English doesnʼt use it at all

Comment: did you try to write down zero, one, few and many? Just don't add an "other" value.

Comment: @TibiG you are trolling me at this point, right? Omitting the `other` variant causes the app to crash, not to mention that English has different rules for plurals than Czech, so it wouldnʼt work anyways.

Comment: it was an honest question. I think it crashes because you have the "other" variant in the default language, or one of the other locales. Try removing it from all versions of the "values.xml" file. However I see you've found a solution.

Comment: @TibiG all right, I wasnʼt sure  I actually deleted the whole `cs` locale and kept only the default one before trying your suggestion. But thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, albeit it is more like a workaround. I used a portion of [gunhansancarʼs LocaleHelper](https://github.com/gunhansancar/ChangeLanguageExample/blob/bbb0f4b21af49a7978721f7dee878361a8d19400/app/src/main/java/com/gunhansancar/changelanguageexample/helper/LocaleHelper.java) and overrode the `attachBaseContext()` method in each activity:

```
public class LocaleHelper {
    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String lang) {
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    private static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }
        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        return context;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase, "cs"));
    }
}
```

Now I have all my Czech strings and plurals in the default `strings.xml` file and the pluralization is working correctly even on non-Czech devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Change locale settings in the app.
public static void setLocale(Context context, String languageCode) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = new Locale(languageCode.toLowerCase());
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics);
}
```

call that method anywhere you want, for exmp :

```
setLocale(this, ENGLISH_CODE);
```